# Decompose string into parenthesed blocks in OCaml

Tags: parsing, ocaml

The purpose of the OCaml code below is to decompose (or "parse")
a string into parenthesed (or possibly non-parenthesed) blocks.

```
(*

Decompose a string into parenthesed blocks.
Sample example at the end of this file

*)

type parenthesis_pair=PP of string*string;;

type data_for_decomposition={
   mutable partial_result : ((parenthesis_pair option)*string) list;
   mutable currently_open_pars : parenthesis_pair list;
   mutable smallest_unprocessed_index : int;
   mutable cursor_location : int; 
};;

let initial_data={
  partial_result=[];
  currently_open_pars=[];
  smallest_unprocessed_index=1;
  cursor_location=1;
};;

let all_parenthesis_pairs=
  [ 
    PP("(",")");
    PP("{","}");
    PP("BEGIN","END");
  ]
  ;;

type small_string=string;;
type big_string=string;;

let test_for_substring_at_index (s1:big_string) (s2:small_string) i=
  if i-1+String.length(s2)>String.length(s1)
  then false 
  else String.sub s1 (i-1) (String.length s2)=s2;; 

let substring_in_interval s i j=String.sub s (i-1) (j-i+1);;

let test_for_left_paren_at_index 
   s i (PP(lparen,rparen))=test_for_substring_at_index  s lparen i;;

let test_for_right_paren_at_index 
   s i (PP(lparen,rparen))=test_for_substring_at_index  s rparen i;;

let look_for_left_paren_at_index s i=
   let rec finder=(fun
    possibilities->match possibilities with
    []->None
    |paren::other_parens->
      if test_for_left_paren_at_index s i paren
      then Some(paren)
      else finder other_parens
   ) in
   finder all_parenthesis_pairs;;

let process_without_open_pars  s data=
   match look_for_left_paren_at_index s data.cursor_location with
     None->(data.cursor_location<-data.cursor_location+1)
    |Some(paren)->
                let (PP(lparen,rparen))=paren in
               let _=(if data.currently_open_pars=[]
               then
                    let i_start=data.smallest_unprocessed_index
                    and i_end=data.cursor_location-1 in
                    let enclosed_substring=substring_in_interval s i_start i_end in
                    let new_result=(None,enclosed_substring) in
                    (
                     data.partial_result<-new_result::(data.partial_result);
                     data.smallest_unprocessed_index<-data.cursor_location
                    )
               ) in
               (
                data.currently_open_pars<-(paren::data.currently_open_pars);
                data.cursor_location<-data.cursor_location+String.length(lparen)
               );;

let process_with_open_pars  s data=
  let nearest_paren=List.hd(data.currently_open_pars) 
  and i=data.cursor_location in
  if not(test_for_right_paren_at_index s i nearest_paren)
  then process_without_open_pars  s data
  else 
       let (PP(lparen,rparen))=nearest_paren 
       and new_list=List.tl(data.currently_open_pars) in
       let _=(
          data.currently_open_pars<-new_list;
        (data.cursor_location<-data.cursor_location+String.length(rparen))
       ) in
       if new_list<>[]
       then ()
       else let i_start=data.smallest_unprocessed_index+String.length(lparen)
            and i_end=i-1 in
            let enclosed_substring=substring_in_interval s i_start i_end in
            let new_result=(Some(nearest_paren),enclosed_substring) in
            (
                data.partial_result<-new_result::(data.partial_result);
                data.smallest_unprocessed_index<-data.cursor_location
             )
            ;;              

let process s data=
  if data.currently_open_pars=[]
  then process_without_open_pars s data
  else process_with_open_pars s data;;

let decompose s=
  let data=initial_data in
  while data.cursor_location<=(String.length s)
  do
     process s data
  done;
  List.rev(data.partial_result);;   

(*

Sample example :

decompose("How (much (research effort) is {expected} when) BEGIN posting a"^
"Code Review ENDquestion? A "^
"lot. {{(An absurd amount)}}. More BEGIN than  BEGIN you think END"^
"you ENDare capable of.");;



*)
```